# SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID not set as environment variable error

Tags: python, environment-variables, spotipy, spotify-app

I'm trying to set up the environment to work with `spotipy` in Python to create a `spotify` recommender system, however, despite passing the environment variables, I keep getting the following error:

```
from http import client
import spotipy
import requests
import os
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials



client_id = os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID')

auth_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials()
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)

playlists = sp.user_playlists('spotify')
while playlists:
    for i, playlist in enumerate(playlists['items']):
        print("%4d %s %s" % (i + 1 + playlists['offset'], playlist['uri'],  playlist['name']))
    if playlists['next']:
        playlists = sp.next(playlists)
    else:
        playlists = None
```

I created a virtual environment to accommodate `pip` packages in Visual Studio 2022 and tried to directly accommodate the environmental var from there.

I also created a `.env.bat` file to set the variables, which didn't set them either. However, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: When you have set environment variables, the first row after the imports and import os aren't needed. Can you please create a test script to print with: import os    print(os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID'),os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET'),os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI'))

Comment: ...so you can check if they are set correctly.